# mySQL changing output unit of ST_Distance function

Tags: mysql, select, spatial

I'm trying to get a result in nautical miles between two lon/lat saved in a point data type field in mySQL. However, the result seems to be not in any unit I'm familiar with (maybe degrees). How can I convert to my preferred unit?. My query as follows...

```
select t1.id, t2.id, ST_Distance(t1.test,t2.test) as DistanceApart from table1
t1 join table2 t2 on (ST_Distance(t1.test,t2.test) <= 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ST_Distance` assumes a flat surface and returns a distance in the same units as the "Points" that are fed to it.

You want [`ST_Distance_Sphere`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html) .  It takes an optional argument, which you should give as the radius of the earth in nautical miles.  Suggest 3440.

But note:  That function was not implemented until Version 5.7.6.  (Not yet in [MariaDB](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467))

Answer (score 2):

### Update Oct, 2018

Hello everyone,

If someone is still landing here wondering for an answer. I have found one. My scope was to get all cities under 50 miles radius of a city selected by the user.

In the database, I have longitude and latitude column of all the cities.

What I did, is that I made a new column loc of "Point" datatype to store the combination of longitude and latitude of each city.

Then lets say user has chosen a city with some $latitude and $longitude, so I get all nearby cities (within 100 miles) as:

```
st_distance(POINT( '.floatval($longitude).', '.floatval($latitude).' ) , loc) <= 1.448
```

Putting this in you WHERE statement of MySQL query will give you all cities under 50 miles radius of that center city.

The formula I found to convert miles in angle is simple:

`1 miles = 1/69.0585729 degree`
Hence,
`50 miles = 50/69.0585729 degree = 0.724 degree` and `100 miles = 100/69.0585729 degree = 1.448 degree`

If you need to have it in km, the formula goes like this:

`1 degree = 111.139 km`

Now you can convert km into degrees as well so that you can compare it with the output of `st_distance()` MySQL function

Please bear in mind that it might exclude some cities as mentioned by Rick in the comments. If you really want to go in depth of it, her eis the link posted by Rick James in the comment section, maybe this can help you out:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

*I hope it helps*

Comment: st_distance assumes a square grid; it fails to take account of the fact that longitude lines are closer together as you go farther from the equator to a pole.  You can partially fix this by multiplying the longitude values by the cosine of the latitude. By punting entirely on `SPATIAL` and using the Haversine formula, you get the 'correct' Great Circle distances.  See [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) for an efficient "find nearest" algorithm.  (It does not involve Spatial.)

Comment: You are right, my solution might leave off some cities on the perimeter so I believe it's either to compromise with accuracy or with execution time/efficiency. As a web app, efficiency gets upper hand in my case. However I will look further into the link you have provided in my free time, maybe I can tackle both requirements.